# Android: mkdir not working

Tags: android, mkdir

I want to create **MyFolder** directory , but cannot to do it, tried different way, but no one working;
In **Androidmanifest.xml** i have:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.package" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
    <!---.....-->
</manifest>
```

**static class**:

```
public static String FILES_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyFolder";
```

**Code**:

```
File dir = new File(Constants.FILES_DIR);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir();
    Log.i("my tag", "isDirectory + " + dir.toString() + " | " + dir.exists() + " | " + dir.mkdir());
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "MyFolder");
    Log.i("my tag", "isDirectory + " + dir.toString() + " | " + dir.exists() + " | " + dir.mkdir());
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "MyFolder/");
    Log.i("my tag", "isDirectory + " + dir.toString() + " | " + dir.exists() + " | " + dir.mkdir());

    Log.i("my tag", "Status + " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
    if (!dir.isDirectory()) return false;
}
```

And logcat:

```
    05-09 14:40:15.131    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ isDirectory + /storage/emulated/0/myFolder | false | false
05-09 14:40:15.131    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ isDirectory + /storage/emulated/0/myFolder | false | false
05-09 14:40:15.136    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ isDirectory + /storage/emulated/0/Music/myFolder | false | false
05-09 14:40:15.136    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ Status + mounted
05-09 14:40:17.261    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ isDirectory + /storage/emulated/0/myFolder | false | false
05-09 14:40:17.261    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ isDirectory + /storage/emulated/0/myFolder | false | false
05-09 14:40:17.261    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ isDirectory + /storage/emulated/0/Music/myFolder | false | false
05-09 14:40:17.266    1453-1453/my.package I/my tag﹕ Status + mounted
```

I also tried **mkdirs();**, path with slash and without, Google it..and finally **I'm desperate**

When i manually crate folder and tried to save file into, i recieve permission error - **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

Comment: try File dir = new File(FILES_DIR);

Comment: @Softcoder FILES_DIR is a constant which place in different class, there i put it together. In logcat we can see that path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my open source projects i use the following class to get the SD Card directory. This is just a simple helper and it should be easy to modify it for any other SD Card directory, or special directory.

```
/**
 * http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html
 *
 * @param albumName
 * @return
 */
public static File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        //This is also the case if the directory already existed
        Log.i("wall-splash", "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

As of creating a file i have the following code:

```
File dir = Utils.getAlbumStorageDir("wall-splash")
//create the file
File file = new File(dir, fileName);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

---

What is the device you are testing on? Does it have external storage? Any custom rom?

---

Try to reboot your device, to make sure nothing is blocked from a previous try.

Comment: as U can see in logcat - Environment.getExternalStorageState() is MOUNTED.
/ 

Samsung Galaxy s4

Comment: @IceJOKER do you also have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? EDIT: ignore this comment "Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission."

Comment: @IceJOKER and the file isn't created. (You just mentioned that the log shows it is not there, but perhaps it is created). As additional thing you can try to create the directory and create a new file to check if it is there.

Comment: @IceJOKER i've edited my previous comment. sorry for this idea. as of the google docs this should not be required

Comment: with READ also not working. I'm desperate , ready for any way to solve the problem. Now i try manually create folder and check is it exists, maybe problem in path.

Comment: Yes, when i manually create folder, exists() working fine, but i cannot to save file, recieve the permission error - open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: do you use a root explorer? if yes perhaps you can change the permissions of the parent folder?

Comment: phone no ROOTED. Anything working nice before, but ...something went wrong

Comment: @IceJOKER can you jump over to the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77379/discussion-between-icejoker-and-mikepenz